# Adding chinese keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am trying to find an .adm or GPO settings so when any users login to the 2003/2008 server using Windows 7/windows xp pro client it will add the keyboard Chinese PRC (one of the inputs that is listed) in the language bar. 
Any ideas or if this is possible much apprieciated.
Thanks

Thanks, it's a client login from a network to the server.

Your adm is for setting up a UK keyboard, I think I have a usa keyboard adm, I have downloaded google pinyin and I need to set it up for PRC (google pinyin) input option under language also any ideas how to write an adm for this as I am not sure how to get the codes etc you have.

Thanks

Comment: Pleas clarify what you mean by "login". Do you mean Terminals Services or just a network connection?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

I wrote a custom adm to do this via group policy (for UK Keyboard Layout) 
more than welcome to use and adapt it..

CLASS USER     CATEGORY "Custom Settings"        CATEGORY "Keyboard Layout"           POLICY "Set UK Keyboard Layout"              KEYNAME "Keyboard Layout\Preload"              VALUENAME 1              VALUEON 00000809              VALUEOFF ""           END POLICY ;Set UK Keyboard Layout        END CATEGORY ;Keyboard Layout     END CATEGORY ;Custom Settings

## INSTRUCTIONS

Step 1: Save the above code as keyboard.adm file into the folder C:Windows\inf on the server

Step 2: Create and link a new GPO (call it something like “Keyboard Layout”)

Step 3: Edit the Keyboard Layout GPO

Step 4: In the Group Policy Editor Window; under User Configuration, right click Administrative Templates and choose Add Template

Step 5: select the keyboard.adm template and click OK until you are returned to the Group Policy Editor window

Step 6: with Templates still selected on the left hand side, select view from the toolbar, and filtering

Step 7: make sure the bottom 2 tick boxes (“only show configured policy settings” and “only show policy settings that can be fully managed”) are un-ticked

Step 8: Browse to the following setting (using the view on the left hand side) User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Custom Settings > Keyboard Layout

Step 9: Enable the policy setting listed on the right hand side (“Set UK Keyboard Layout”)

Comment: Your adm is for setting up a UK keyboard, I think I have a usa keyboard adm, I have downloaded google pinyin and I need to set it up for PRC (google pinyin) input option under language also any ideas how to write an adm for this as I am not sure how to get the codes etc you have.

Thanks